# How to iterate a list of integer pairs, computing new 'union pairs'

Tags: python

I have a list of integer pairs representing year ranges and need to compute union ranges for pairs that are contiguous (within 1 year).

**example input:**

`ts_list = [[1777, 1777], [1778, 1783], [1786, 1791], [1792, 1795]]`

**desired output**

`[[1777, 1781], [1786, 1795]]`

I've tried for and while loops, and can get the union before the first disjoint, but I'm stumped as to how to iterate properly -- e.g. this produces  a newlist of

`[[1777, 1783], [1778, 1783], [1786, 1795]]`

then returns a Type error: `'int' object is not subscriptable"`. The first and third pairs are correct, but the 2nd is extraneous

```
ts_list = [[1777, 1777], [1778, 1781], [1786, 1791], [1792, 1795]]
newlist=[]
last = ts_list[len(ts_list)-1][1]
for x in range(len(ts_list)):
   ts=ts_list[x]
   start = ts[0]
   end = ts[1]
   ts_next = ts_list[x+1] if x<len(ts_list)-1 else last
   if ts_next[0]-end > 1:
       # next is disjoint, break out
       newlist.append([start,end])
   else:
       # next is contiguous (within 1 year)
       newlist.append([start,ts_next[1]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
ts_list = [[1777, 1777], [1778, 1781], [1786, 1791], [1792, 1795]]

# We start with the first range
out = [ts_list[0]]
for start, end in ts_list[1:]:
    if start <= out[-1][1] + 1:
        # if the new range starts at most one year
        # after the end of the previous one, we extend it:
        out[-1][1] = end
    else:
        # otherwise, we append this new range to the output
        out.append([start, end])

print(out)

# [[1777, 1781], [1786, 1795]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using set/list comprehensions:

```
ts_list = [[1777, 1777], [1778, 1781], [1786, 1791], [1792, 1795]]


# Get all years that are contained in one of the date ranges, including start and end year.
# Using a set ensures that each year appears only once.

all_years = {y for years in ts_list for y in range(years[0], years[1] + 1)}


# Get start years (years where the previous year is not in all_years)
# and end years (years where the following year is not in all_years).

start_years = [y for y in all_years if y - 1 not in all_years]
end_years = [y for y in all_years if y + 1 not in all_years]


# Combine start and end years. To match the right ones, sort first.

start_years.sort()
end_years.sort()
result = [[start_year, end_year] for start_year, end_year in zip(start_years, end_years)]


print(result)
# [[1777, 1781], [1786, 1795]]
```